# Changing the position of UIView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I need to set the position of UIView. The code below shows how I do it. But it does not work. How do I do this?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

      CGRect frame = myview.frame;
      frame.origin.x = myview.frame.origin.x;
      frame.origin.y =   0;
      myview.frame = frame;

NSLog(@"%d", frame.origin.y );

}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `myview` is not `nil`?

Answer (score 1):

UIView's have a center property..if you want to change the position then just use that... rather to resize whole view

```
myview.center = CGPointMake(50, 250);
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that your OUTLET is connected to your view in the nib file.**

Comment: Your code is perfect & it is working for me. Just only make sure that your outlet must be connected in your xib file.

Comment: Is this helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this in viewDidAppear method,it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Move view/ change the position of view with animation**

*if you want to change the position of View as you want then just use following lines of code :*

.h file :

```
- (void)moveView:(UIView *)view withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
        andCurve:(int)curve inDirection_X:(CGFloat)x inDirection_Y:(CGFloat)y;
```

.m file :

```
- (void)moveView:(UIView *)view withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
        andCurve:(int)curve inDirection_X:(CGFloat)x inDirection_Y:(CGFloat)y
{
    // Setup the animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    // The transform matrix
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, y);
    view.transform = transform;

    // Commit the changes
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

*Note : To call above method anywhere just do like it , 
As per your requirement i.e. how to move view/ change the position of view with animation*

```
 [self moveView:mFrontSideView withDuration:2.0 andCurve:0 inDirection_X: 0.0  inDirection_Y: mBackSideView.center.y + 100.0];
```