# Issue with subviews overlapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, subview, addsubview

I'm trying to create a custom view which containes several images. I do that by adding them programmatically. The problem is that those subviews overlap each other and I can't find the way to change that. The only solution I can see is doing something like setting frames for each new image programmatically. I would be grateful if someone could tell me what is the best way to solve this issue.

```
for (id image in self.images) {
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [self.imageViews addObject:imageView];
    [self addSubview:imageView];
}
```

Comment: How you want to collect them?Like a few image in one image or do you wanna like something UICollectionView?

Comment: You need to [define a frame][1] for each UIImageView or use [constraints][2] to layout them.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442142/changing-the-position-of-uiview
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826878/creating-layout-constraints-programmatically

Comment: Yeah, as @grhnkdlk said U can show them as cells in UICollectionView. Maybe it is the best way to do this. It gives all the flexibility of layout and U can adjust margins, images count, handle swipes and so on.

But if U need a simple way to add just a couple of images to the custom View, perhaps several images, that may exist or maybe not depending on some condition: 1) Set frames and maybe autosizing mask (but be ready for possible troubles with layout if orientation changes) 2) Or set the autolayout constraints and don't use frames at all

Comment: Thanks to all of you ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using Interface Builder your only real options are to change the frame or the center.

```
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(x coord, y coord, width, height);
```

This method lets you resize and move whereas changing the center lets you do just that, move the center of the view.

or

```
imageView.center = CGPointMake(x coord, y coord);
```

Or as recommended add constraints.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna make your `customView` like `UICollectionView` you need a `UIScrollView` and add your `subviews` in it. Everytime when you add a subview change frame location so it could be something like this:

```
int xPosition = 0;
int yPosition =0;
for (id image in self.images) {

    if (xPosition>self.view.frame.size.width) {
        //give size to every imageView and every time in loop change the location
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, 50, 50)];
        imageView.image = image;
        yPosition = yPosition + 50;
        [self.view addSubView:imageView];
    }
    else {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, 50, 50)];
        imageView.image = image;
        xPosition = xPosition + 50;
        [self.view addSubView:imageView];

    }


}
```